# FS без повторений?

Tags: javascript

Как записать текст в файл без повторений?

```js
fs.appendFile('d:\\a\\logs.txt', `[${today}] [${displaytime}] `+message.toString()+"\n", err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return
    }
})
```

Этот код добавляет в файл текст с повторениями, а мне надо без повторений. Как это сделать?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду под повторениями. Подразумеваете, что этот фрагмент может записывать в файл одинаковые строки, если переменные today и displaytime содержат одинаковые данные и `message.toString()` тоже совпадает? То есть повторения появляются после нескольких таких вызовов? Имеете ли вы в виду и частичное повторение, то есть время может быть разное, но одинаковые сообщения не должны повторятся?

Comment: частичное повторение, то есть время может быть разное, но одинаковые сообщения не должны повторятся

Answer (score 1):

Мне в голову приходит два способа.

1. С дополнительными затратами на память. Создайте структуру [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) и заносите в неё все сообщения, которые выводите в файл. Перед выводом проверяйте наличие в ней идентичных сообщений и выводите, только если их там нет.
2. С дополнительными затратами на чтение файла и парсинг. Перед выводом читайте содержимое файла, делите его на строки и проверяйте на наличие идентичных сообщений.

Первый способ может скушать много дополнительной памяти, если у вас большие объёмы данных. Второй способ будет отбирать время на чтение файла и разбор — а если файл большой, вместо постоянно занятого куска памяти вы будете занимать такой же кусок время от времени.

Возможно, кто-то подскажет более удачные решения.

Comment: Можно бы для чуть более быстрого поиска завести N файлов, в которых будут отдельно построчно записываться все сообщения (всё, что начинается с буквы a - идет в a.txt, начинается с b → в b.txt и т.д. — по первой букве сообщения значительно сузить область поиска). Это при условии, что ничего не знаем про базы данных :)

Comment: Да, ещё первый способ менее надёжный: если вдруг скрипт время от времени аварийно перезагружается, данные в памяти будут каждый раз теряться.